# ipython and jupyter notebooks not autocompleting(Fixed, Solution explained)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

My Original Error:
I am new to python and am using anaconda 4.8.3. When I try to autocomplete after math. or sentence. nothing shows up. I have tried installing both pyreadline and jedi, but both are already installed with anaconda apparently. I have not disabled or enabled anything outside of the normal process of learning to use conda, like setting up shells and feeling out how to use ipython/notebooks.

The Fix that I was able to find:
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
Put this line of code literally anywhere, I recommend making a separate text file for this specifically if you are having this issue, and you just need to run it before coding. You will need to do this every time that you open up the notebook but aside from that it is an easy fix. If you know anyone with this problem please share this with them. So far I have not found anything else that works for me, so if there is a more permanent option I would love to see it.

Comment: Did you try pressing <TAB> after math. or Ctrl +<Space>. In my case it always works.

Answer (score 0):

For ipython version 7.19.0 add the following to your ipython config file. default is at where your other profile files are lurking at

.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py

```
c.Completer.use_jedi=False
```

Looks like some stability issues are still being worked on.

ref [IPython core.completer](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.completer.html#IPython.core.completer.rectify_completions)